# How do I copy values (and not the formatting) within a With..End With block?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, copy

I have tried incoperating .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues and .value in to the code. But can't seem to get it right.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wsSource, wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim i, iLastSource, iRowTarget, count As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Stig Jan")
iLastSource = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Laura Jan")
count = 0
With wsSource
iRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For i = 36 To iLastSource
  Set cell = .Cells(i, 4)
  If cell.Font.Bold = False Then
    If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
      .Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy wsTarget.Range("A" & iRowTarget)
      wsTarget.Range("D" & iRowTarget).ClearContents
      iRowTarget = iRowTarget + 1
      count = count + 1
    End If
  End If
If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
 wsSource.Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Font.Bold = True
End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. Was experimenting just before posting. Should be right now :s

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens with your current code?

Comment: No, it works fine. But i just want the values copied and not the formatting. i know that other people with this problem use .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues or .value facing this problem. But i am fairly new to coding, so cant seem to get it incoperated.

Comment: It says '424' f.ex. when i put .value before copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use value transfer, change:

```
.Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy wsTarget.Range("A" & iRowTarget)
```

to

```
wsTarget.Range("A" & iRowTarget & ":H" & iRowTarget).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Value
```